Convergence of a sequence of function $t^n\sin(1-t)$
I should check if sequence of function $x_n(t)=t^n\sin(1-t)+t^2$ converge in $C[0,1]$. I find that if it converges, it has to be $x_n \to x(t)=t^2$.
So I have to prove $\max(t^n\sin(1-t) ) \to 0$, but I can't prove this
I tried to divide this interval on $[0,\epsilon]$ and $[\epsilon,1]$ and prove that max on both goes to $0$, but I have that $\epsilon$ is depended on $n$. Any tips?

Hint: $0 \le t^{n}\sin (1-t)\le t^{n}(1-t)$. If $t >1-\epsilon$ then  $t^{n}(1-t) \le 1-t <\epsilon$. For $t \le 1-\epsilon$ we have $t^{n}(1-t) \le t^{n}$ Can you finish?

Yes, thank  you!

The sequence $x_n(t)$ is decreasing and convergent pointwise to  $x(t)=t^2$ (a continuous function). By  Dini's theorem the convergence is uniform.
Concerning an explicit estimate, with no use of derivatives, we have
$$0\le x_n(t)-x(t)=t^n\sin(1-t)\le t^n(1-t)$$
For $0<t\le 1$ we get
$$ t^{-n}=\left (1+{1-t\over t}\right )^n\ge n{1-t\over t}\ge  n(1-t)$$ Thus
$$t^n(1-t) \le {1\over n},\quad 0\le t\le 1$$
